# How to get full internet connection when testing other speed in other countries?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, connection

*I don’t know where to ask about this but here goes nothing hopefully someone can shed some light on this thing.*

---

I live in UAE (United Arab Emirates) in the Middle East and my Internet connection is 250Mbps down and 105Mbps up. My PC is an ASUS PC running Windows 10.

I tested more websites and sometimes they give less or more than that like 5Mbps to 10Mbps more or less. But thats not the issue.

The issue is when I test to the UAE iI get that speed. But when testing — lets say for example — to France am getting 20Mbps down and like 4Mbps up. Why is that? I mean while my friend in the U.S. when testing to the UAE he loses like 10Mbps say from each 100Mbps.

It gets weird when I tested my phone on 5ghz Wi-Fi I get 110Mbps download and 90Mbps upload?

So I went back and connected my PC to wireless to test. And yes I know wireless is slower than cable but I just wanted to test. So I connected to the 5ghz Wi-Fi network but still on my PC I am getting 20Mbps download and 3Mbps to 4Mbps upload.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same server in france when comparing mobile vs desktop?

Comment: yes i am using the same server, but France was an example the point here is when i test with my phone other countries its faster than my pc

Comment: guess am the only one with this issue, i have a feeling i need to get a network card or whatever but kinda want some1 to confirm it first o.o